# sql implementation and data entry

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a database to hold all the sample data shown [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzHKn6rZZbVZZTRWNFJYc3ZYQnM/view?usp=sharing)

Below is the entity diagram i created. I managed to forward engineer this into sql but I am having problems entering data for rean and leases so far it is telling me that I cant have duplicate data. i think it has to do with my design. I would appreciate any help on design that will allow me to enter all the sample data and some explanations. Im new to sql.I am using sql workbench 6.3.

[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Do post a **minimal** schema that demonstrates what you're trying to achieve and replicates the problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to show the insert statements you have done and note which ones failed.

Comment: @Roberto their are few issues in your DB design if you can provide the create table statement i can help you on modifing them

Comment: So far I have just learned to use sql workbench I create the relational diagram and then forward engineee it into the database and start entering the data